# concatenation of two map into a single java class

Tags: java

Please advise me the correct approach to concatenate the map into single map returned by two classes, shall i make one another class which will do the concatenation , my class structure is looks like

First come the interface

```
public interface masterCardRule {

    public Map<String, List<NTM>> exceute(String jobCode, 
            String clientlogo) throws Exception;
}
```

then come the two classes ,first one named masterCardBusinessANFRuleImpl

```
public class masterCardBusinessANFRuleImpl implements masterCardRule {

    // **contains all setters and getters and below the method 
    // executed that returns map after logic **

    public Map<String, List<NTM>> exceute(String jobCode, 
            String ClientId) throws Exception {
        buisness logic 
    }
}
```

and then comes the second class named masterCardBusinessCNFRuleImpl

```
public class masterCardBusinessCNFRuleImpl implements masterCardRule {

    // **contains all setters and getters and below the method 
    // executed that returns map after logic **

    public Map<String, List<NTM>> exceute(String jobCode, 
            String ClientId) throws Exception {
        buisness logic 
    }
}
```

now please advise how can i combine the concatenation of map into one , so shall i introduce the top level class over it,so that user will call that class and then further these two classes will be called and then sum of there map by adding the result of two individual map into the final map and returned to the caller, so that caller will get a single map by simply calling a single class, please advise how can i do that .

rite now i am calling these two classes as

```
 Map<String, List<NTM>> issuerNTMMap1 = MasterCardADDCNF.exceute(projectMapping.getSpJobCode(), keyInfoModel.getClientLogo());

Map<String, List<NTM>> issuerNTMMap2 =  MasterCardADDANF.exceute(projectMapping.getSpJobCode(), keyInfoModel.getClientId());
```

Comment: Your solution depends very much on how `masterCardBusinessANFRuleImpl` and `masterCardBusinessCNFRuleImpl` are instantiated and invoked. Can you please show the code that calls the `exceute` method?

Comment: @ErnestKiwele while i am calling these two classes as an individual rite now

Comment: What about `issuerNTMMap1.putAll(issuerNTMMap2)`? and then just use `issuerNTMMap1` after that? Or is your question about how to design the interface/contract so that the client only makes one call?

Comment: @ErnestKiwele please advise can i combine the map into outer class and then the caller class will call that outer class from that outer class these two individual classes getting called and then in that outer class map of both the classes will concatenate

Comment: @ErnestKiwele yes you got it my question is ow to design the interface/contract so that the client only makes one call

Comment: Well, it seems to me that it's the client/caller that knows about the implementation classes, therefore, it's incorrect to put that "combined" data concern in the interface. I'd suggest you either manually combine the 2 maps or create a caller-side helper that delegates calls to multiple implementations of the interface, but this is a concern of the caller.

Answer (score 2):

If you use java8 you can make a stream of the two maps,  **map** them to entrysets then **flatmap** them to stream of entries then **collect** them to a Map by entry keys merging the values(lists) with merge function in the **tomap**() method in the Collectors class.

Sorry for mistakes, I'm posting from the phone

```
package com.example.demo;

import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class A {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    class B {

    }
    class C extends B{}

    Map<String,List<B>> map1=new HashMap<>();
    map1.put("one", Arrays.asList(new B(),new B()));
    map1.put("two", Arrays.asList(new B()));

    Map<String,List<B>> map2=new HashMap<>();
    map2.put("one",Arrays.asList(new C(),new C()));
    map2.put("three",Arrays.asList(new C()));

    Stream.of(map1,map2)
          .map(Map::entrySet)
          .flatMap(Set::stream)
          .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                   Map.Entry::getKey,
                   Map.Entry::getValue,
                   (val1, val2)->{
                          val1.addAll(val2);
                          return val1;
                   }
                   ));
    }
}
```

for **Java7:**

```
package com.example.demo;

import java.util.*;

public class A {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    class B {

    }
    class C extends B {
    }

    Map<String, List<B>> map1 = new HashMap<>();
    map1.put("one", Arrays.asList(new B(), new B()));
    map1.put("two", Arrays.asList(new B()));

    Map<String, List<B>> map2 = new HashMap<>();
    map2.put("one", Arrays.asList(new C(), new C()));
    map2.put("three", Arrays.asList(new C()));

    for (Map.Entry<String, List<B>> entry : map2.entrySet()) {
        String key = entry.getKey();
        List<B> vals = map1.get(key);

        if (vals == null || vals.size() == 0) {
            map1.put(key, entry.getValue());
        } else {
            vals.addAll(entry.getValue());
        }
    }
  }
}
```

if you sure that one map is much smaller then the other there is a sense to iterate through the smallest one, you can check sizes before iterations

Comment: Thanks please post as per Java 7 standards

Answer (score 0):

I think you should change your interface to

```
public Map<String, **Collection**<NTM>> exceute(String jobCode,String clientlogo) throws Exception;
```

You can return from Rule implementation `Map<String, Set<NTM>>`

Then provide an Aggregator Implementation which will implement the same interface
and would call your Rule classes.

For combining the map in your Aggregator, you can do something like

```
for (String key: map1.keySet()){
  if(map2.contains(key){
  map2.get(key).addAll(map1.get(key));
  }
} 
return map2;
```

Answer (score 0):

Look for the `putAll` method is the `HashMap` class.

You can essentially do `issuerNTMMap1.putAll(issuerNTMMap2)` and return `issuerNTMMap1`.

Answer (score 0):

`Apache Commons Collection` provides a `MultiValueMap` class:

> A MultiValueMap decorates another map, allowing it to have more than one value for a key.

Consider changing your return type from `Map<String, List<NTM>>` to `MultiValueMap<String, NTM>`. In this case you could simply write:

```
issuerNTMMap1.putAll(issuerNTMMap2);
```